# How to find parent node with specific name?

Tags: java, aem, parent, groovy-console

```
def query = SQLQuery() <- my sql query
def result = query.execute()
result.nodes.each{node -> 
    node.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_TITLE, "new3")
```

I found all components with a certain resource type using groovy consoly, and I need to replace their titles with the titles of the pages in which this component is located.
I need to use parent node named `jcr:content`

Instead of "new3" i can use `node.getParent().getParent().getParent().getProperty("jcr:title")`,but pages can have different structures. So, how to find parent node by name ?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to find the `Page` containing a resource would be via [`PageManager#getContainingPage`](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html#getContainingPage-org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource-).

Once you've got a `Page` object, you can read the relevant title. Keep in mind that there are a few options to choose from:

- [`title`](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getTitle--)
- [`pageTitle`](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getPageTitle--)
- [`navigationTitle`](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getNavigationTitle--)

They can map to different dialog fields in the Page properties and certain components may use them differently, sometimes using fallbacks from one to another in case a value is absent. Same goes for different page-level components which may or may not allow authors to set a given property.

The exact use should be [pretty clear if you use AEM Core Components](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/pull/834/files) but custom components may need a bit of investigation, especially if you're dealing with a long-lived codebase.

If none of the titles is a good fit, you could use the [`name` of the page](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getName--) which should match its node name in the repository.

The `PageManager` itself should be available as a [default binding in the Groovy console, under `pageManager`](https://github.com/CID15/aem-groovy-console/blob/0efb96bef6239a46fa9c2664fbb68e21a56213c8/bundle/src/main/groovy/org/cid15/aem/groovy/console/extension/impl/DefaultBindingExtensionProvider.groovy#L43). Alternatively, it can be adapted from a `ResourceResolver`, e.g. if you need some custom permissions.